# Unable to get refresh token in github oauth2

Tags: github, oauth-2.0, refresh-token

I have integrated social login using Github oauth2, Im able to get access token but not refresh token.

As per their documentation [here](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/refreshing-user-to-server-access-tokens#opting-out-of-expiring-tokens-for-new-github-apps) I can enable in Optional features section. But there Im not seeing any such option and seeing "There are no optional features to try right now."

Is there any way I can enable refresh token in github oauth2

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same thing. You've created OAuth application, but it was necessary to create GitHub app instead